# Array value replacement from array within array in iPhone

Tags: nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have array output like this.

```
 {
    id = 1;  
    user = {
            name="ABC"
            }
 },  
{

    id = 2;  
    user = {
            name="XYZ"
            }
 },
```

I have to change id with number 5 and 6 and name with "asd" and "fgh". My array definition is here.

```
      myArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:statuses];
```

And here is my approach for chaning of "id".

```
 [[myArray objectAtIndex:0]replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"5"];
 [[myArray objectAtIndex:0]replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"6"];
```

But I am getting following acception.

```
 [__NSCFDictionary replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to  instance 0x6511810
 Terminating app due to uncaught    exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6511810'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myArray seems to be NSArray which is Immutable.

How did you declare myArray?

EDIT:

```
First:
```

myArray = [statuses mutableCopy];

Second:

```
[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] setObject:@"5" forKey:@"id"]; 
[[myArray objectAtIndex:1] setObject:@"6" forKey:@"id"];
[[[myArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"user"] setObject:@"asd" forKey:@"name"];
[[[myArray objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"user"] setObject:@"fgh" forKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Try instead :  myArray= [statuses mutableCopy];

Comment: I changed but still same problem.

Comment: [[myArray objectAtIndex:i] setObject:@"5" forKey:@"id"]; - this is the mistake ; this is the way you update because you have a dictionary inside.

Comment: Will it not change "id" to 5? and how will i change username which is inside of "user"? Thanks